# How to approximate $x^y$ using a quadratic function

Tags: algorithms, exponential-function

I need to build an algorithm that finds the approximately $x^y$ where $x = [0, 1]$ and $y = [0, 0.4)$.
This is for a computer algorithm (the standard library is too slow). I thought about making a lookup table but that would require a 2 dimensional table (since I have 2 variable). I would be ok with a lookup 1 dimensional lookup table.
Ideally the function would be most accurate at around x=1, y=0.16

Comment: You can use the taylor expansions for ln x and exp(x).

Comment: isn't taylor expansion only for e^x ?

Comment: Use $x^y = \exp(\ln(x)\cdot y)$

Comment: This may be useful: $x^y \approx \exp \left(y\frac{x-1}{6}\left(1+\frac{8}{1+x}+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) $

Comment: For $x\in\bigg[\dfrac23,\dfrac32\bigg]$, we have $\ln x\simeq\sqrt x-\dfrac1{\sqrt x}$ .

Answer (score 1):

If there is an inbuilt exponential function, then you can use the following equation to approximate it in the given intervals:

$$x^y \approx \exp \left(y\frac{x-1}{6}\left(1+\frac{8}{1+x}+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$$

The inner term is an approximation to ln(x) using Simpson's Rule, which is quite accurate. You can use a lookup table or a taylor series or some approximation if the inbuilt exp is not fast enough.

The accuracy is quite good, see this graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/75cebv9qks .
The green and blue lines coincide so nicely that they are not even visible seperately.

Near 0.16, its not that accurate and you may use 2 or 3 terms of the [Simpson's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpsons_rule).

Comment: >in the given intervals< would it be too much to ask you how you made up this function ? or even just paste some links that explain how to build those ?

Comment: Good answer. It seems to only get within about 0.05 of the actual value near 0.16 though.

Comment: Actually its the Simpson's rule for numerical integration. I used the formula to approximate ln(x) as the inner term using the fact that $\ln(x)=\int_1^x \frac1x$.

Comment: @theREALyumdub I thought it was near y=0.16, not x=0.16. It is quite accurate near x=1.

Comment: I used Kartik's graph, which is x^x. So you are probably correct that y is the problem

Comment: no it is near y=0.16, x=1 that it should be most accurate

Comment: @user2475269 Then it is quite accurate and you dont need more terms.

Comment: I just realised if i do make a lookup table, i could probably modify the values in the lookup so that it corrects for the error introduced by simpsons rule

Answer (score 0):

The commenters are right that exp(ln(x) * y) is the most efficient way to do this. On the other hand I have an over-complicated way to do it below, which may be slightly faster because it uses a look-up table.

I'm not sure I exactly understand what you mean by quadratic function, at first I thought you meant the complexity had to be quadratic, but it sounds like you are asking legitimately for a polynomial. I think it should suffice to say that polynomials do not approximate exponential functions such as the above, because the ratio of an exponential function changes drastically, where a polynomial approaches a fixed number (The lead coefficient multiplied by the factorial of the degree, I believe...).

You could make a binary look up table as follows, and make it small enough steps to suit your accuracy with numbers in between.

$$ y = a_n \frac{1}{2^n} + a_{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} + ... + a_1 \frac12 $$
$$ x^y = a_n x^{2^{-n}} * a_{n-1} x^{-2^{n-1}} * ... * x^{a_1} $$

Note the above formula is right associative. By pre-computing the values of $ x^{2^{n}} $, one can multiply them together depending on the value of y and it's binary form, and pre-compute for different values of x to the desired n-depth for accuracy.
Even I don't think that is the better answer, it may be slightly faster in a time sensitive situation.

Comment: I didn't realize that polynomial function could not approximate these. I edited my question.

Comment: Actually, I may be wrong about that. Give me a second

Comment: Also, I don't know if you're about to edit your post, but what are the values of a_n

Comment: They are the binary booleans for y, ie if y = 5, 101 in binary, they are the digit numbers

Comment: try using taylor expansions truncated at x^2. Note that the function looks like a line above about y= 0.5 and that should be used for good accuracy there